# Creating a Maven/JSF/Primefaces project at Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying create a Maven/JSF/Primefaces project at Eclipse JUNO.
I have JRE1.8 but when set this JRE my Maven project is checked with red X showing that contain a error.

I don't know why this problem occurs because Eclipse doesn't display any exception.

Any suggestion ?

[image][image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Look in the Problems view (Window > Show View > Problems)

Comment: Did you check the Problems view?

Comment: And why Eclipse Juno? You should at least use [Kepler SR2 that has Java 8 support](http://eclipse.org/downloads/java8/). Luna already has embedded support.

Comment: guys ...I solved the problem. I was Window>show view>markers and was really marked problem with JRE1.8 version. I did quick fix and change 1.5 to 1.8 on quick fix, now works. thanks.